# How to show only specific formGroups?

Tags: angular

I have a complicated nested group forms:

```
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
     'type': new FormControl(),
     'formGroup1': this.formBuilder.group({'date': new FormControl()}),
     'formGroup2': this.formBuilder.group({'types': new FormArray([])}),
  });
```

I want to display form depends value of `this.form.get("type").value`. If value is `1` show only `formGroup1`, if `2` then`formGroup2`.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" class="dialog_form" autocomplete="off">
   <input type="text" formControlName="type">
   <!-- Subforms here
</form>
```

How to do that?

Comment: you can add a `*ngIf` to display what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do like

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" class="dialog_form" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" formControlName="type">

    <form *ngIf="form.get('type').value === 1; else f2" formGroupName="formGroup1">
        ...
    </form>

    <ng-template #f2>
        <form formGroupName="formGroup2">
            ...
        </form>
    </ng-template>
</form>
```

Hope useful

Comment: Thank you, what id more sub forms?

Comment: not use `form` inside another `form`, use `<div formGroupName...></div>`

Comment: Could you share an example? Should it be form tag always?

Comment: <div *ngIf="this.form.get("type").value == 1; else f2" formGroupName="formGroup1">
         <input type="text" formControlName ="date" >
       </div>
      <ng-template #f2>
       <div *ngIf="this.form.get("type").value == 1; else f2" formGroupName="formGroup2">
         <input  >
       </div>